# Passing config options from file to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, browserify

In my PHP project, there is a javascript code that is supposed to use some values defined in a config file. So, I'm looking for best way to to pass config values to javascript, without mixing php and js. I was thinking that this might be accomplished with Node.js, where config file would be read and parsed, and then this Node module would be converted into browser JS with browserify. Is this even possible ?

Comment: Huh, you want to use Node to read a config file for PHP? Why not just get the config file with PHP and echo it somewhere in the DOM ?

Comment: Why bother setting up node.js for something as trivial as `file_get_contents` + `echo json_encode($dataFromFile);`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mix PHP code with JS code you can run ajax call in javascript to a php function that returns JSON with data you need.

End of function in PHP would be something like:

```
exit(json_encode($data));
```

and in javascript (with jquery):

```
$.post("script.php", {}, function(data) {
    var configParams = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: That's one solution, I didn't think of that, nice.